# ImpressPages 4.5.1 seems to be missing the theme setting after install

Tags: php, themes, impresspages

I have just installed a fresh copy of ImpressPages 4.5.1 and I am getting the following error after install:

```
require(/var/web/testsite/public/pagesdemo/Theme//main.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/web/testsite/public/pagesdemo/Ip/View.php:111
Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/web/testsite/public/pagesdemo/Theme//main.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/web/testsite/public/pagesdemo/Ip/View.php on line 111
```

I can confirm that write access was given to the proper directories as I made the entire structure www-data.www-data read/writable (as this is a test environment I am not concerned about any security at this point).

As you can see in the path however it is showing "pagesdemo/Theme//main.php" which to me is indicating that somewhere it missed definition of the Theme (thus is blank).

Is there a way to set this theme manually (where is the configuration? database? config file?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The theme can be set in the database by creating a following record:

Plugin: Ip
Key: theme
Value: "Air"   //Quotes are important. As this must be json'ed value.

Looks like reinstalling would be also not a bad idea.

Comment: After digging through the source code, I was able to find that key/value information, but when I entered it in the database (without quotes), of course it did not work, so thanks for letting me know why :)  Alternatively I also found that you could add the 'theme' => 'Air', into the config.php file in the root directory (which did solve my problem as well)  On a final note I have tried reinstalling several times, and on two different virtual test machines, with the same results.  Not sure why I am having the trouble, but its fixed now, thanks!

Comment: *note* I have added a bug report to the github repository as well.